Showing $\int \limits_{a}^{x}f(t)(x-t)\,dt=\int \limits_{a}^{x}\left(\int \limits_{a}^{t}f(s)\,ds\right)dt$
I am working for hours on this task. Can someone help me?
Here is the task: $\int_{a}^{x}f(t)(x-t)\,dt=\int{a}^{x}(\int_{a}^{t}f(s))dt$.
I got some hints:
i) $\text{ Set }F(t)=\int_{a}^{t}f(s)ds$,
ii) Find F'(t)
iii) Use Integration by parts
I am not quite sure if my thoughts are right:
i) $\int_{a}^{x}(\int_{a}^{t}f(s)ds)dt=\int_{a}^{x}F(t)dt=F°(x)-F°(a)$
ii) $\frac{d}{dt}F°(x)-F°(a)=F(x)-F(a)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$
What is the next step?

Haven't tried this, but the first thing that occurred to me was (1) show LHS and RHS have same value at (say) $x=a$ (easy), and then (2) show LHS and RHS have same derivative. If $g$ and $h$ are continuous and $g'(x) = h'(x)$ everywhere (assuming a connected domain) and $g(x_0) = h(x_0)$ at some $x_0$, then $g=h$.

Note that the $x$ is treated as a constant, and $F'(t) = f(t)$. So proceed with the hint above:
\begin{align*}
& \int_{a}^x\left(\int_{a}^t f(s)ds\right)dt =
\int_{a}^x F(t)dt =
\left. F(t)\,t\right\vert_{a}^{x} -
\int_{a}^{x} t\,f(t)dt
\\[5mm] = & \
xF(x)-aF(a)- \int_{a}^x t\,f(t)dt =
\int_{a}^x xf(t)dt- \int_{a}^{x}t\,f(t)dt
\\[5mm] = & \
\int_{a}^{x} (x-t)f(t)dt
\end{align*}
We're done !

Thank you. It looks very easy so far. But how did you show                                       xF(x)-aF(a)=$$\int \limits_{a}^{x}xf(t)dt$$?

@MathStudentRUB: It's from the fundamental theorem of calculus the reverse version.

Thank you. I think about that:)

Isn't there a problem with the notation? I mean I understand that we use the fundamental theorem of calculus, but do we have to substitute x another letter?

@MathStudentRUB: The trick of this problem is the $x$. It looks as if it is a variable w.r.t $t,s$ but it is a constant.

Switching $ds$ with $dt$, one has $$\int \limits_{a}^{x}\left(\int \limits_{a}^{t}f(s)\,ds\right)dt=\int \limits_{a}^{x}\left(\int \limits_{s}^{x}f(s)\,dt\right)ds=\int \limits_{a}^{x}f(s)(x-s)\,ds=\int \limits_{a}^{x}f(t)(x-t)\,dt.$$

Nice trick, but our professor didn't introduce it yet. So we are not allowed to use it:/

Assuming that $f$ is a smooth function, we can write,
$F_b(t) = \int_b^t f(s) ds$
for any $b \in \mathbb{R}$.  This function has two important properties,
(i) $F_b'(t) = \frac{d}{dt} \int_b^t f(s)ds = f(t)$
(ii) $F_b(b) = \int_b^b f(s)ds = 0$
Using (i) we can re-write the given integral as,
$\int_a^x f(t) (x-t) dt = \int_a^x (x-t) F_b'(t) dt$
This is done with integration by parts,
$\int_a^x (x-t) F_b'(t) dt= [(x-t)F_b(t)|_a^x - \int_a^x F_b(t) \frac{d}{dt} (x-t) dt $
$= -(x-a) F_b(a) + \int_a^x F_b(t) dt$
Now, we make use of (ii) by choosing $a = b$ so that the term $(x-a)F_a(a) = 0$, and this yields the desired result.

I have two issues: i)

As you start with integration by parts I think it should be: $$\int \limits_{a}^{x}(x-t)f(t)dt=[(x-t)F(t)]{a}^{x}-\int \limits{a}^{x}-f(t)*1dt=[(x-t)F(t)]{a}^{x}+\int \limits{a}^{x}f(t)dt=(x-x)F(x)-(x-a)F(a)+\int \limits_{a}^{x}f(t)dt=0-(x-a)F(a)+\int \limits_{a}^{x}f(t)dt.$$ I don't understand how we use ii) in the last step. Can you help me out? I think you have done it very well:)

You're right there was an error with the limits, which resulted in a sign error.  As for (ii), the anti-derivative F(t) is not unique, you can add any constant you like to it without disrupting property (i).  In particular, this means we can set the function F  to zero at any single point like x=a.

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$
f(t)=\frac{d}{d t} \int_a^t f(s) d s, 
$$
then via integration by parts yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_a^x\left(\int_a^t f(s) d s\right) d t 
= & {\left[x \int_a^t f(s) d s\right]_{t=a}^{t=x}-\int_a^x t f(t) d t } \\
= & x \int_a^x f(s) d s-\int_a^x t f(t) d t  \\
= & \int_a^x(x-t) f(t) d t
\end{aligned}
$$
